# How to examine details of an e-mail I received?

Tags: security, email

I believe I've heard that you can find things like:

- IP Address an email was sent from
- Machine Name an email was sent from
- Various other bits of information that are not visible when viewing an email

If you look at the innards of an email.  Is this true or am I way off base?  If it can be done, how do I go about finding that information?

The email is from a Yahoo account.

UPDATE:

The email is *to* an Outlook account.

Comment: Most big E-Mail providers seem to have stopped adding that kind of information even if the mail was sent through SMTP (as opposed to webmail). It's still possible in some cases to get the information out of the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "Full Message Headers" would show you all information about an email.  You can find that in Yahoo Mail by clicking Actions > View Full Header.

Not sure if any bits get stripped, but I could at least see the IP address the email message came from.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo! mail lets you expand and view all the headers of the message. The headers have all that info.

Answer (score 0):

In gmail, there is an optional called "Show Original", but what is there very much depends upon the behavior of gmail and the mail relays the message passed through.

For instance, an email from another gmail user shows hardly anything, while a newsletter from an external service shows a much larger amount and variety of information (it's obviously got to come from outside gmail).